# Rewrite URL with .htaccess to PHP router

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to achieve two level URL structure with which I can manipulate content in the index.php router file. It's not working as intended with the code below. When accessing site.com/one the $page variable (GET) needs to return "one" and also if I access site.com/one/edit the $page variable should still be "one" with additional variable $action, which would be "edit".

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2 [NC,L]
```

The code above returns $page variable as "one/edit" if I access site.com/one/edit.

Comment: Change the order and try? Put last rule first and first rule below it.

Comment: Try them the other way around. The first rewriterule expression includes any possible match for the second rule, so it's quite possible the second rule is never hit.

Comment: Seems like it's working. Thanks a lot